# Creating arrays with reference variables and casting

Tags: java

I am preparing for the OCA Java SE 8 exam and there is a code example that shows errors that I don't understand.

It is about creating arrays with reference variables and casting arrays.

Here is the code:

```
String[] strings = { "stringValue" };
Object[] objects = strings;
String[] againStrings = (String[]) objects;
againStrings[0] = new StringBuilder(); //Error 1: Does not compile
objects[0] = new StringBuilder(); //Error 2
```

`Error 1`, I do understand but not `Error 2`. The book says:

> A `StringBuilder` object can clearly go into an `Object[]`. The problem is that we don't actually have an `Object[]`. We have a `String[]` referred to from an `Object[]` variable.

I am not sure where this is happening. Is the casting the reason why the `String[]` is referred to from an `Object[]` variable?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Explore the java exception which you are receiving. It will explain most of the issues :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because on line#2

```
Object[] objects = strings; <--- here
```

You have set objects as the **reference** of the variable **strings**.

And at the line#5, you are trying to update the value of objects[0] which now represents a reference to **strings**

Therefore 
`strings = new StringBuilder()` <--- turns out to be a failure hence the error.

I hope this makes sense?

Comment: Yes, that makes sense. Thanks for the help! :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you want to assign a StringBuilder object to an element of a string array. By using `objects[0]` on the left-hand side of the assignment in line #5, you make use of the reference stored in `objects` which points to a string array, as assigned in line #2. Subsequently, you try to store a StringBuilder object into the first element of this string array which fails because no implicit type casting is possible from StringBuilder to String.

However, the following would work instead:

```
StringBuilder[] buildersArray = {new StringBuilder()};
objects = buildersArray;
```

This is because it just overwrites the reference stored in `objects` with a new reference to another array that matches the declared type (StringBuilder is a subclass of Object). In this case the string array formerly stored in `objects` is not even touched.